# What is a SQL Server 2017 function to separate strings on different characters regardless of length

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split

I am using SQL Server 2017 and I have a field that has strings of different lengths
Sometimes the separator is '/' or  space' ' but I want them to treat this the same when separating. Also the length of the characters after each separator varies.

Strings example : AB020102/2014(MN), AB0102/2015(L), AB020102 2017

Desired Results: I want to separate like below:

1. AB020102/2014(MN) = AB,020102,2014,MN
2. AB0102/2015(L) = AB, 0102,2015,L
   , AB020102 2017= AB, 020102,2017,NULL

I tried this
select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE('AB020102/2014(MN)'),0,CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE('AB020102/2014(MN)')))) Office

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
select s.value
from string_split(translate('AB020102/2014(MN)', '/()', '   '), ' ') s
where s.value <> '';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e8f98422d71f48313d5fc94da10b8f1a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What is the fist from for

Comment: Thanks. This makes perfect sense. Can i split this into different fields as well?

Comment: @MoyahaboRabothata . . . With much more trouble, unless you know the number of columns that would be created.  Perhaps you should ask a question with a bit more information about what you are trying to do.